# change size of one menu item border in joomla

Tags: css, joomla

this is my menu items code:

```
#moonavigator li.level1 > .item-link span {
display: block;
width: 115px;
height: 50 px;
padding: 3px 8px;
border-radius: 0px;
border: 1px solid #4FBBAB;
text-align: center;}
```

and I want one item to have the width of 300px; I did it like this:

```
.class2 li.level1 > .item-link span {
display: block;
width:300px;
}
```

and added the class name to the menu item, in the link css style, but nothing is changes. how can I solve this?

Comment: did you try the `!important` declaration?  `.class2 li.level1 > .item-link span { width:300px !important; }`

Comment: which element has class .class2?

Comment: one of my menu items that I want to change it's border size

Comment: in that case `li.level1.class2 > .item-link span { width: 300px !important; }`

Comment: It's not working and I can't figure out why, It all seems correct

Comment: Providing a link to your website will definitely help resolving this problem.

Comment: it's on localhost, but I can show a picture

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
#moonavigator li.class2 > .item-link span { width: 300px !important; }
```

I think it will working.